# Python reading lines in a txt file and writing to new txt file: "l" not readable

Tags: python

If the input.txt has the following:

- Min: 1,2,3,5,6
- Max: 1,2,3,5,6
- Avg: 1,2,3,5,6
- Your program should generate output.txt as follows:
- The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1.
- The max of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6.
- The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4.

I am trying to right to a new text file and all seems to be working except for the minimum that is not working as something is wrong with my definition.

Please can someone assist and advise.

Thank you.

```
in_file = open("input.txt", "r")
out_file = open("output.txt", "w")

def get_min(l): #I am not sure how to fix this as "l" can not be found
    return min(nums)

def get_max(l):
    return max(l)

def get_avg(l):
    return sum(l) / len(l)

for line in in_file:
    parts = line.split(":")
    cmd = parts[0].strip().lower()
    nums = parts[1].strip().split(",")
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = int(nums[i])
    
    if cmd == "min":
        out_file.write("The min of [" + ", ".join([str(i) for i in nums]) + "] is " + str(get_min(nums)) + "\n")
    elif cmd == "max":
        out_file.write("The max of [" + ", ".join([str(i) for i in nums]) + "] is " + str(get_max(nums)) + "\n")
    elif cmd == "avg":
        out_file.write("The avg of [" + ", ".join([str(i) for i in nums]) + "] is " + str(get_avg(nums)))

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: how are you calling these functions?

Comment: @Naveed please find the rest of my code.

Comment: You are defining `get_min` to take `l` as parameter, but you use `min(nums)` in the function itself. So `l` is actually unused.
Aside from that I don't get any error running your code with `min: 1,2,3` in `input.txt`.

Comment: Thank you @el_gio how would you define it? If I use "l" as a parameter and "l" in the function it does not work either?

Comment: I am literally brand new at this.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'it does not work'? Are you getting an error, or the output is not the expected one?

Comment: Sorry, after many frowns and coffee's, I figured out my text file was the issue. All is working as it should. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
in_file = open("input.txt", "r")
out_file = open("output.txt", "w")

def get_min(l):
    return min(l)

#Defini
def get_max(l):
    return max(l)

def get_avg(l):
    return sum(l) / len(l)

for line in in_file:
    parts = line.split(":")
    cmd = parts[0].strip().lower()
    nums = parts[1].strip().split(",")
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = int(nums[i])

    
    
    if cmd == "min":
        out_file.write("The min of [" + ", ".join([str(i) for i in nums]) + "] is " + str(get_min(nums)) + "\n")
    elif cmd == "max":
        out_file.write("The max of [" + ", ".join([str(i) for i in nums]) + "] is " + str(get_max(nums)) + "\n")
    elif cmd == "avg":
        out_file.write("The avg of [" + ", ".join([str(i) for i in nums]) + "] is " + str(get_avg(nums)))

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```